# Is there any way to change the value of constant in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
use constant TESTVERSION => 2;
```

In my code, I want to change the value of the constant based on some check. If the condition is true, I should use same TESTVERSION and if false, I have to use some different version. Is it possible in perl to update the constant value at run time?

Comment: Why would you want to use a constant that needs to be a variable? Why not just use a variable? Literally the only difference between a constant and a variable is that a constant cannot be changed.

Comment: Well, another difference is the syntax, which you might need to fix in thousands of lines.

Answer (score 7):

[constant](http://p3rl.org/constant) behaves as a sub with empty prototypes that always returns the same value, so it can be inlined. Redefine it with a real subroutine.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use constant TESTVERSION => 2;
my $TESTVERSION = TESTVERSION;
{   no warnings 'redefine';
    sub TESTVERSION() { $TESTVERSION }
}

for my $condition (0, 1) {
    $TESTVERSION = 3 if $condition;
    say TESTVERSION;
}
```

Comment: I'd be really, really careful with doing this, for two reasons: 1) that's an implementation detail that could be changed in the future; 2) because of this, from the [`constant` perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/constant): "In the current implementation, scalar constants are actually inlinable subroutines. As of version 5.004 of Perl, the appropriate scalar constant is inserted directly in place of some subroutine calls, thereby saving the overhead of a subroutine call."

Comment: @JoeCasadonte: Yes, the inlining happens at compile time. So does the `sub` declaration, so if you redefine the constant right after its declaration, no inlining will happen.

Comment: it's been decades since I've looked into the Perl internals that deeply; thanks for the info.

Answer (score 6):

No, a constant has to be defined at compile-time (or at least before the code using is compiled). But nothing stops you from doing your check at compile-time.

```perl
use constant TESTVERSION => cond() ? 2 : 3;
```

or

```perl
sub test_version {
   return cond() ? 2 : 3;
}

use constant TESTVERSION => test_version();
```

or

```perl
my $test_version;
BEGIN {
   $test_version = cond() ? 2 : 3;
}

use constant TESTVERSION => $test_version;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need run-time definition of constant values, then I would suggest using something other than the `contant` pragma. Overriding the subroutine will be confusing to future maintainers, IMO. I've personally never liked it because of the syntax restrictions (e.g. lack of string interpolation).

For small scripts, I use a coding standing: I define them in their own section, and give them names in ALL CAPS. Yes, that relies on people not violating the standard as it's not enforced/enforceable. I mostly work with professionals and we have mandatory code reviews, so it's never been a problem.

For larger projects, I use the [Readonly](https://metacpan.org/pod/Readonly) module. It's old, but it works for me.

For more options and discussion, see an old-ish blog post by Gabor Szabo: [Constants and read-only variables in Perl](https://perlmaven.com/constants-and-read-only-variables-in-perl)